# jooq String to Integer conversion

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I`m new in Jooq. I want to convert string to integer.

Defined in Table1:-

```
TableField<?, Integer> city_id;
```

Defined in Table2:-

```
TableField<?, String> city_id;
```

In select query.

```
dsl.select()
   .from(Table1)
   .leftOuterJoin(Table2)
   .on(Table1.city_id.eq(Table2.city_id))
   .fetch();
```

Since city_id is in different format in Table1 and TABLE2. So it need to convert city_id of table2, from String to Integer and vice versa
I tried with
          Integer.valueOf(), Integer.parseInt(), not working.

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jOOQ docs (https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/cast-expressions/) describes the usage of `cast()` where it could be used within the statement to cast a field to another type.

Using your example:

> Defined in Table1:-

```
TableField<?, Integer> city_id;
```

> Defined in Table2:-

```
TableField<?, String> city_id;
```

> In select query.

```
dsl.select()
   .from(Table1)
   .leftOuterJoin(Table2)
   .on(Table1.city_id.eq(Table2.city_id))
   .fetch();
```

The statement using cast to convert Integer to String:

```
dsl.select()
   .from(Table1)
   .leftOuterJoin(Table2)
   .on(Table1.city_id.cast(String.class).eq(Table2.city_id))
   .fetch();
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Ideal solution: `CAST()`

[Koshux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44018505/521799) has provided a great answer, which you should probably use as explicitly casting the types won't leave conversion to chance. You get to choose yourself whether:

- The numeric column is cast to the string type
- The string column is cast to the numeric type

I'm just showing two more options:

#### Coercing:

There's a [`Field.coerce()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html#coerce-java.lang.Class-) method that "coerces" a jOOQ `Field` reference to a different type without this having any effect on the generated SQL. E.g.:

```
dsl.select()
   .from(Table1)
   .leftOuterJoin(Table2)
   .on(Table1.city_id.eq(Table2.city_id.coerce(Table1.city_id)))
   .fetch();
```

#### Rawtype casting:

Just as with coercing, you may resort to rawtype casting for the same effect (unless you're using [converters](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/custom-data-types/) or [data type bindings](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/custom-data-type-bindings/)):

```
dsl.select()
   .from(Table1)
   .leftOuterJoin(Table2)
   .on(Table1.city_id.eq((Field) Table2.city_id))
   .fetch();
```

#### Side note:

Of course, it would be better to use the same type in both tables, and enforce integrity with an actual foreign key constraint.